# SQLite : Select from the end of tree to the top

Tags: sqlite

from this awesome [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23502164/3599629), now i can implement recursive query properly ,

and here i have another question,

first:

i create a table :

```
 CREATE TABLE tree(
 id_tree integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
 id_boss TEXT,
 id_child TEXT,
 answ TEXT);
```

insert some value :

```
 INSERT INTO tree(id_boss,id_child,answ) VALUES('1','2','T');
 INSERT INTO tree(id_boss,id_child,answ) VALUES('1','3','F');
 INSERT INTO tree(id_boss,id_child,answ) VALUES('2','P1','T');
 INSERT INTO tree(id_boss,id_child,answ) VALUES('2','4','F');
 INSERT INTO tree(id_boss,id_child,answ) VALUES('3','P2','T');
 INSERT INTO tree(id_boss,id_child,answ) VALUES('3','8','F');
```

and then i running a recursive query from this awesome [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23502164/3599629) :

```
WITH RECURSIVE
under_alice(name,level,order_nr) AS (
  VALUES('1','0',0)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT tree.id_child, under_alice.level+1, tree.id_tree
    FROM tree, under_alice
   WHERE tree.id_boss=under_alice.name 
   ORDER BY 2 DESC, 3
)
SELECT substr('..........',1,level*3) || name FROM under_alice;
```

the result will be like this :

```
  1
  ...2
  ......P1
  ......4
  ...3
  ......P2
  ......8
```

**"Edited"** ------>

and my question is, is this posible to reverse it, 
for example i choose id_child = **'P2'**, result will be :

```
  P2
  3
  1
```

and if i choose id_child = **'P1'** :

```
  P1
  2
  1
```

Comment: Node `1` is not on the same level as `2` and `3`. Do you really want them to have the same `...` indent?

Comment: @cl no , i just want to show the number value, not with the level, i edited my question, please see my question again .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recursive query starts at `P1`:

```
VALUES('P1')
```

In the recursion step, we go from some record (`ancestor`) to its parent by looking up the `id_boss` value of that entry:

```
SELECT tree.id_boss
FROM tree JOIN ancestor ON tree.id_child = ancestor.id
```

Everything together:

```
WITH RECURSIVE
ancestor(id) AS (
    VALUES('P1')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT tree.id_boss
    FROM tree JOIN ancestor ON tree.id_child = ancestor.id
)
SELECT id FROM ancestor;
```

Comment: thanks you so much , thanks for helping me, thanks for helping me understand the code to ,
thanks and thanks again, you're saving me .

Comment: hey , i have another question again, is it possible to not select id_boss that have a `F` value ? so if i choose `P2` the result will be just `3` , value `1` thats in `F` is not show up